# How to declare an ad hoc polymorphic type be an instance of an specific type class?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I have a type class named `ManagedValue` defined as follows:

```hs
class ManagedValue a where
    type ManagedPtr a = (r :: *) | r -> a
    withManaged :: a -> (ManagedPtr a -> IO b) -> IO b
    getManaged :: ManagedPtr a -> IO a
    castManagedToPtr :: ManagedPtr a -> Ptr b
    castPtrToManaged :: Ptr b -> ManagedPtr a
```

For every type that is an instance of `Storable` typeclass, it is also an instance of `ManagedValue` typeclass, but not all `ManagedValue`s are storable. However, I can't define it as something like `instance Storable a => ManagedPtr a where ...` becasue *GHC* gives the error `The constraint ‘Storable a’ is no smaller than the instance head ‘ManagedValue a’`.

I know I can define a type class hierarchy as `Num` to `Intergral` like `class (Storable a, ManagedValue a) => StorableValue a where ...`. But this way needs to define all the instances manually, which is tiresome.

What I want is to declare that all `Storable` values are also `ManagedValue` so that I can define an instance just in one place and get the implementations for `Int`, `Double` and so on automatically, something like:

```hs
-- This definition doesn't work
instance Storable a => ManagedValue a where
  type ManagedPtr a = Ptr a

  withManaged v f = do
    fp <- mallocForeignPtr
    withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
       poke p v
       f p

  getManaged p = peek p

  castManagedToPtr = castPtr
  castPtrToManaged = castPtr
```

Then I can implement the methods of `ManagedValue` for `Int`, `Double`, et al.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [default method signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/default_signatures.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable

class ManagedValue a where
    type ManagedPtr a = (r :: *) | r -> a
    type ManagedPtr a = Ptr a

    withManaged :: a -> (ManagedPtr a -> IO b) -> IO b
    default withManaged :: (Storable a, ManagedPtr a ~ Ptr a) => a -> (ManagedPtr a -> IO b) -> IO b
    withManaged v f = do
        fp <- mallocForeignPtr
        withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
            poke p v
            f p

    getManaged :: ManagedPtr a -> IO a
    default getManaged :: (Storable a, ManagedPtr a ~ Ptr a) => ManagedPtr a -> IO a
    getManaged p = peek p

    castManagedToPtr :: ManagedPtr a -> Ptr b
    default castManagedToPtr :: ManagedPtr a ~ Ptr a => ManagedPtr a -> Ptr b
    castManagedToPtr = castPtr

    castPtrToManaged :: Ptr b -> ManagedPtr a
    default castPtrToManaged :: ManagedPtr a ~ Ptr a => Ptr b -> ManagedPtr a
    castPtrToManaged = castPtr
```

You'll still have to write `instance ManagedValue Int`, `instance ManagedValue Double`, etc., but you won't have to implement anything inside of those instances.

---

There's another option that wouldn't require you to manually write any `instance`s for things that are `Storable`, but it has some caveats of its own:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable

class ManagedPtr r where
    type ManagedValue r
    withManaged :: ManagedValue r -> (r -> IO b) -> IO b
    getManaged :: r -> IO (ManagedValue r)
    castManagedToPtr :: r -> Ptr b
    castPtrToManaged :: Ptr b -> r

instance Storable a => ManagedPtr (Ptr a) where
  type ManagedValue (Ptr a) = a

  withManaged v f = do
    fp <- mallocForeignPtr
    withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
       poke p v
       f p

  getManaged p = peek p

  castManagedToPtr = castPtr
  castPtrToManaged = castPtr
```

I basically turned the typeclass inside-out here, putting the typeclass on the pointer type and having the value be an associated type. The main caveat there's no longer a dependency from the value type to the pointer type, so when you actually use this typeclass, you'll probably have a ton of ambiguous types that you need to resolve with `TypeApplications` or something. The second caveat is that `ManagedPtr` can only ever be a `Ptr` now if the underlying value is `Storable`.

Comment: Thanks! It's really help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks again! In my case the first solution is better, which gives a better readability of my code. Besides, since I also have to implement an instance for `String` by `type ManagedValue CString = String`, the second solution gives a `Conflicting family instance declarations` error. Just to write the instance declaration is simple enough for my case.